# Sharepoint - Programatically check Project Task list hierarchy

Tags: splistitem, task-list

I have a Project Task list in Sharepoint that contains Summary Tasks, which contain Tasks. What I would like to do, is to check which task items of this list are children elements of which summary task items. I know we can check the type of the item with SPListItem.ContentType, but I can't see any way to get the hierarchy of the items. The is the SPListItem.XML field which kind of help, but maybe there is a simpler way? Perhaps casting SPListItem to some type, unfortunately, I haven't found any information about that. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I found that the `querystring` for tasks contains RootFolder parameter, it is quite helpful, still maybe someone has a better approach